# Cython: Segmentation Fault Using API Embedding Cython to C

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to embed Cython code into C following [O'reilly Cython book](https://github.com/hnakamur/exposing_cython_code_to_c/tree/master/mechanism2) chapter 8. I found this paragraph on Cython's [documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#c-api-declarations) but still don't know what should I do:

> If the C code wanting to use these functions is part of more than one shared library or executable, then import_modulename() function needs to be called in each of the shared libraries which use these functions. If you crash with a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV on linux) when calling into one of these api calls, this is likely an indication that the shared library which contains the api call which is generating the segmentation fault does not call the import_modulename() function before the api call which crashes.

I'm running Python 3.4, Cython 0.23 and GCC 5 on OS X. The source code are `transcendentals.pyx` and `main.c`:

`main.c`

```
#include "transcendentals_api.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Py_SetPythonHome(L"/Users/spacegoing/anaconda");
  Py_Initialize();
  import_transcendentals();
  printf("pi**e: %f\n", pow(get_pi(), get_e()));

  Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

`transcendentals.pyx`

```
cdef api double get_pi():
    return 3.1415926

cdef api double get_e():
    print("calling get_e()")
    return 2.718281828
```

I'm compiling those files using `setup.py` and `Makefile`:

`setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize([
        Extension("transcendentals", ["transcendentals.pyx"])
    ])
)
```

`Makefile`

```
python-config=/Users/spacegoing/anaconda/bin/python3-config
ldflags:=$(shell $(python-config) --ldflags)
cflags:=$(shell $(python-config) --cflags)

a.out: main.c transcendentals.so
    gcc-5 $(cflags) $(ldflags) transcendentals.c main.c

transcendentals.so: setup.py transcendentals.pyx
    python setup.py build_ext --inplace
    cython transcendentals.pyx


clean:
    rm -r a.out a.out.dSYM build transcendentals.[ch] transcendentals.so transcendentals_api.h
```

However, I came to error `Segmentation fault: 11`. Any idea can help with this? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you try `import transcendentals` from python interpreter? On my computer, `ImportError: /tmp/q/transcendentals.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeUTF8`. ` import_transcendentals()` returns `0` on success and `-1` on failure i.e. the return value should be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that Makefile there is

```
transcendentals.so: setup.py transcendentals.pyx
    python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Unless `python` refers to `/Users/spacegoing/anaconda/bin/python3` it should be replaced since the module may be compiled for wrong python version, and cannot thus be loaded.

In *main.c* there is call `import_transcendentals()` that does not check the return value i.e. if the import fails or succeeds. In case of failure, `get_pi()` and `get_e()` point to invalid memory locations and trying to call them causes a segmentation fault.

Also, the module has to be located somewhere where it can be found. It seems that when embedding, the current directory is not searched for python modules. `PYTHONPATH` environment variable could be changed to include the directory where *transcendentals.so* is located.

The following is an altenative way of embedding the code to the C program and sidesteps the import issues since the module code is linked to the executable.

Essentially, a call to `PyInit_transcendentals()` is missing.

File *transcendentals.h* will be generated when the cython functions are defined `public` i.e.

```
cdef public api double get_pi():
...
cdef public api double get_e():
```

Your *main.c* should have the include directives

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "transcendentals.h"
```

and then in `main`

```
Py_Initialize();
PyInit_transcendentals();
```

There should be no `#include "transcendentals_api.h"` and no `import_transcendentals()`

The first reason is that according to the documentation

> However, note that you should include either modulename.h or
>   modulename_api.h in a given C file, not both, otherwise you may get
>   conflicting dual definitions.

The second reason is, that since *transcendentals.c* is linked to the program in

```
gcc $(cflags) $(ldflags) transcendentals.c main.c
```

there is no reason to import transcendentals module. The module has to be initialized though, `PyInit_transcendentals()` does that for Python 3

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, according to official doc `api` should be a replacement of `public`. Even in the official example it doesn't call `PyInit_transcendentals();`. Would you please explain why your method works?

Comment: After checking the documentation, I think my method is actually an alternative way and I'm not sure why that `import_transcendentals();` is not working.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. One last question, would you please explain my quote?

Comment: @spacegoing that quote referring to need to call `import_modulename()` or there will be a segmentation fault, is related to function pointer definitions defined in *modulename_api.h* (like `get_e()` and `get_pi()`. Without successful `import_modulename()` call, those pointers point to invalid memory locations and calling the functions will cause a segmentation fault.