# Cython PYD is a DLL, is there an easy way to embed Python into an executable calling it?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, dll, cython

I'm trying to embed Python into a C++ .exe using NumPy, Pandas, SciPy, and some compiled Cython PYD files.  There are some instructions for embedding Python but these don't really extend to additional libraries: to ensure this works on Windows machines lacking my version of Python, I am using the embedded library for 3.5.1 here which has little documentation on its use: https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html#embedded-distribution

And before calling `Py_Initialize()`, I extract the `python35.zip` file from the embedded distribution and place it in the project directory, then reference it as described here: http://www.myoddweb.com/2016/02/27/embed-python-in-your-c-application-without-python-installed-on-guest-machine/ i.e.

```
#include <Python.h>
std::wstring python_path;
python_path += L"\\pythonlibs\\python35.zip";
Py_SetPath(python_path.c_str());
Py_Initialize();
```

For some reason, I cannot get the compiled version to run.  I have tried to keep Python separate from my system build.  I'm still referencing the Numpy includes from my system path though `C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include`, not sure if that is problematic.  All my code is fast because I'm using NumPy `MemoryViews` and optimized Pandas data manipulation, which I need to keep.  Not a MSVC expert here so just looking for anyone who can guide me in the right direction embedding Python.  Much appreciated.

Comment: `python_path += L"\\python35.zip";` will refer to something like `C:\python35.zip` which is probably not what was intended.

Comment: Good call @J.J.Hakala I copied the .zip out to the C:\ and now it just crashes when trying to init the Python interpreter instead of displaying the error messages...  Unhandled exception at 0x0000000000000000 in EmbedPythonNumpyC++.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000. when I launch the debugger. Closer to getting it up and running at least

Comment: Sorry about the above I realize memory addresses don't help anyone troubleshoot...    // Do some work.
    outer_work_1d(num_x, some_1d_data, answer);
    std::cout << "\nexample_application.main: answer_1d = " << *answer << std::endl; crashes after the pointer to *answer here I believe:     // Call into the Python module and do some work.
    inner_work_1d(num_x, some_1d_data, answer);    // Defined in wrapper_inner_api.h

Comment: If you are following the [demo code](https://github.com/Who8MyLunch/Python-Embed-Demo/blob/master/wrapper_outer.hpp), there is at least one issue: code like `import_wrapper_inner()` that does not check the return value. I have tried to explain what that might cause in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38028619/5781248). You could try to set PYTHONPATH environment variable to point to the directory where your extension module and other things are.

Comment: Thanks @J.J.Hakala that may come in handy in the future. I'm still having issues compiling that test script as you mentioned, but may try doing this embedding another way.  Changed my question to reflect the new purpose.